# I need to let the user update the data entered into textbox to be reflected back to the specific user's detail into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

My query now is that I have developed a user homepage using session variables which will be holding the user's name and user's Email and show these sessions into the homepage aspx page, now I need to let the specific user edit and update the registered email and after updating it the database also need to get updated with the new email field values for that specific user. Now in the database I have a table called `tblcontacts` which holds four columns as `name`,`fname`,`E-mail` and `studentID`. Please help me, how do I locate and select the concerned row to update the details using LINQ query code.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Homepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.Homepage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h1> Welcome!&nbsp; </h1>
        <p> &nbsp; <img src="user.jpg" /></p>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
&nbsp;Your Registered e-mail is:
        <asp:Label ID="lblmail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Edit" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; New-Email :&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Wrong Format!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class Homepage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static int check = 0;
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblName.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
            lblmail.Text = Session["email"].ToString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tblContact tb = new tblContact();
            check += 1;
            if (check % 2 == 0)
            { 
              
                tb.Email = TextBox1.Text;
                TextBox1.Visible = false;
                Button1.Text = "edit";
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Visible = true;
                Button1.Text = "Update";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Doing Some Investigation for the desired code finally i fixed this by removing the line in code as tb.email = textbox1.text and after adding following two lines of code in button click event handler function :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblContact tb = new tblContact();
        check += 1;
        if (check % 2 == 0)
        { 
           var student = (from c in db.tblContacts where c.name == lblName.Text select c).Single();
           student.Email = TextBox1.Text;
            TextBox1.Visible = false;
            Button1.Text = "edit";
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
            Button1.Text = "Update";
        }
    }
```

The single method here in LINQ query made it work to select the desired row in the table for which the details are to be updated!This answer has to be marked correct,as this solved by query